# How we can show one product from each subcategory in product page

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.5.1, Any of you know
**How we can show one product from each subcategory on a category page and when the user click on the proudct that listed on the category page it will go to the concern subcategory page where all products are displayed**

For Ex : 
Assume I have a category name **A** , With subcategory **AA**, **AB**, **AC**, **AD**, **AE**
**AA** Have 5 Products Name **AA1**, **AA2**, **AA3**, **AA4** ,**AA5**
**AB** Have 4 Products Name **AB1**, **AB2**, **AB3**, **AB4**
**AC** Have 3 Products Name **AC1**, **AC2**, **AC3**
**AD** Have 4 Products Name **AD1**, **AD2**, **AD3**, **AD4**
**AE** Have 3 Products Name **AE1**, **AE2**, **AE3**

When i load my category page , it should display one product from each subcategories, is that possible? if so, how can it be done

Comment: Placing a bounty after two days already without any line of code looks counter-productive. I mean it's your reputation, however, first of all I would suggest you to contact Opencart support (as this sounds like a support request) and then I would wait what they write back to you and then probably if you have problems to do what they suggest you ask here (or even better: in a forum about opencart, Stackoverflow is about programming in general).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pseudo code below just giving you idea don't know about the **opencart** version you are using so just go through the below code  to  display one product from each subcategory

In your project directory open `catelog/controller/product/category.php` and in the `index()` function you will get the category id i.e. `$category_id` parent category id where you are standing , put the code before you render the controller i.e. `$this->response->setOutput($this->render());`

```
/**********************************************************************/
        $getsubcate=$this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);
        $subcatedata=array();

        for($s=0;$s< count($getsubcate); $s++){
            $subcatedata[$s]=array(
            'name'=>$getsubcate[$s]['name'],
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $getsubcate[$s]['parent_id'] . '_' . $getsubcate[$s]['category_id'])
            );
            $data = array(
                        'filter_category_id' => $getsubcate[$s]['category_id'],
                        'sort'               => $sort,//your sorting param
                        'order'              => $order,// your ordering param
                        'limit'              => 1
                    );

            $subcatedata[$s]['product'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
        }
       $this->data['subcategory']=$subcatedata;


        /****************************************************************************************/
```

Now open your theme's category template if you are using default's one then path would be  `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl` and if custom theme then open the category.tpl of your theme `catalog/view/theme/your theme name/template/product/category.tpl`

And place this code where ever you want to show the subcategories with single products or multiple products

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($subcategory);$i++) { ?>
  <h1>Sub Categories</h1>
<ul>
  <?php if (isset($subcategory[$i])) { ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $subcategory[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $subcategory[$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
    <div class="product-list">
      <?php foreach ($subcategory[$i]['products'] as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
        <div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
          <br />
          <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="cart">
          <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
        </div>
        <div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></div>
        <div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it works perfectly

> If you are not happy with code then you can buy this extension which
>   does the similar job

[**Sort by sub category**](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&token=b4381909f29ca2d2511830b09f09fa84&extension_id=11190)

Comment: @down voters grow up and show some respect and add your comments what problem you see in the  bounty answer

Answer (score 1):

As you already know main category, you can:

1)

```
SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE parent_id = {A.category_id}
```

2)

Loop all categories from above with category_id:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.id WHERE ptc.category_id = category_id ORDER BY p.product_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

It's not tested queries. Modify them by your needs.